# java.util.Properties and Cp1250

Tags: java, encoding, properties, default, cp1250

Can I use java.util.Properties with encoding different then default?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why would you need that? You'd break the assumptions of all the halfway-reasonable tools that handle .properties files.

Comment: I use properties file as map written to disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not unless you

1. are running java 6 or later
2. control the code loading the properties file, and can use a Reader.  See [the javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)).

This is a pretty annoying flaw in the spec.  There are several workarounds, probably the simplest being to auto-generate a unicode-escaped compliant .properties file from an encoding-appropriate (cp1250, utf-8, whatever) source.

Java ships with a transcoder called [native2ascii](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/native2ascii.html) to do this for you:

There are some aged RFEs on this subject:

- [Provide UTF-8 based properties resource bundles](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6204853) - 2004
- [Need a load(Reader)/store(Writer) interface for Properties class](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4094886) - 1997

Comment: While it might be seen as a flaw in the spec, I think it's a good thing that the encoding of a .properties file is well-known and specified in the spec as opposed to being variable and non-defined.

Comment: We certainly agree that it's good that the spec defines an encoding.  
It's bad that the spec neither defined a wide-gamut encoding like utf-8 nor a method of dynamically switching encoding early in the file, e.g. XML

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but then you have to be careful to use the [`load()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) and [`store()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store(java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String)) methods that take a `Reader`/`Writer`, and explicitly construct those by using an `InputStreamReader/OutputStreamWriter` with the correct encoding.

This may not be possible with libraries that use properties files implicitly.

**Edit:** The methods described above have only been introduced in Java 1.6 - for older versions, you're out of luck, as dsadinoff wrote.

Answer (score 1):

If your properties file is available at build time, you can also convert it in your ant script using the native2ascii task:

```
<property name="javac.source.encoding" value="Cp1250"/>

<native2ascii src="${src.dir}" dest="${classes.dir}"
   encoding="${javac.source.encoding}"
   includes="**/*.properties"/>
```